# How to read a Firestore document?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Android development ... ;-)

I need to know how to read a specific document I saved to Firestore, without having to copy the "documentPath" manually from the Cloud Firestore Console!

How do you do this automatically?

Next, I put some of the code where the **documentPath** is that I need to configure:

```
DocumentReference user = mFirestore.collection("Users").document(idUsers).collection("Companies").document(**"documentPath"**)
```

link to the image:

[Company that I registered now and that I wish to need to show the user automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4XJv.png)

link to the document:

[Document fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGkYW.png)

I'm testing the following class:

```
private void ReadSingleEmpresa() {

        FirebaseAuth autenticacao = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
        String idUsuario = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

        DocumentReference user = mFirestore.collection("Users").document(idUsuario).collection("Companies").document("gaSpr59pbeMmO9UpFxQQ");//document path

        user.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

                    if (document.exists()) {
                        Log.d("ler doc", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());

                        StringBuilder fields = new StringBuilder("");

                        //Some document fields
                        fields.append("Company name: ").append(document.get("nomeEmpresa"));
                        fields.append("\nEmail: ").append(document.get("emailRepresentante"));
                        fields.append("\nTelephone number: ").append(document.get("telefoneRepresentante"));

                        txtEmpresa.setText(fields.toString());


                    } else {
                        Log.d("ler doc", "No such document");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("ler doc", "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    }
                });
    }
```

This is the result:

[Result of reading some document fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKBLZ.png)

It works but I do not know how to get the document I just registered among several. I only get it when I manually copy the document ID ...

Comment: To be able to load the document for a specific company for a specific user, you will need to know the full path to that document. So you will either need to know ID of that user, and the ID of that company, **or** you will need to know something else that allows you to look up those IDs using a query.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your database and indicate the exact document that you want to get. Please also responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo Ready. I added a screenshot ... hope it helps

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you indicate some example that uses query in this sense?

Comment: @caetanoatoa So you want to get `gaSp ... FxQQ` document? If so, please show us the content of that document.

Comment: @AlexMamo That's it. When the user signs up a new company, the fields will be saved in the firestore. Then a screen with this data will be displayed.

Comment: @caetanoatoa You didn't answer my question. You want only to get **`gaSp ... FxQQ`** document?

Comment: @AlexMamo I need to get one document at a time, not only "gaSp ... FxQQ" document. For this test I used the document "gaSp ... FxQQ". I would like to get a document shortly after saving it in the firestore and show the user.